# How to find all pairs (a, b) in an array such that (k % a) % b = (k % b) % a

Tags: python, modulo

Given an array with `n` elements ( 1 to n), the task is to find the pairs in the array such that `(k % a) % b = (k % b) % a` where `k` is a given integer.

I tried the naive approach

```
for a in range(1, n + 1):
    for b in range(a + 1, n + 1):
        if (k % a) % b == (k % b) % a:
```

This code has the complexity of O(n²) so I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Where does `i` come from?

Comment: @mkrieger1 check the edit.

Comment: Where does `b` come from? Did you mean `a + 1`?

Comment: @quamrana Yes sorry for that. thats  a+1

Comment: Are there bounds provided for k, n, element of the array? Do you have a link to the original question?

Comment: Your naive approach doesn't access an array.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't do better than O(n^2) because theoretically, all O(n^2) pairs could satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n^2)` is a tight bound. Consider any input where `k` is smaller than every element in the array. Then `k % a == k` and `k % b == k`, so the condition is trivially satisfied for every pair `(a, b)`.